# How do you tag a question where the language does not matter

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask if anyone has come across a library or open source project to do a specific task that I do not want to code from scratch. I don't care about the language used by the library as long as it meets certain criterion (can run on a linux server, can handle very large input....). How should I tag that type of question? Is SO the right place for that type of question?

Comment: Tag it [tag:language-agnostic].

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." => don't ask on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You could try asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

There is a specific tag [library](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/library) for this purpose:

> code libraries to write programs to accomplish specific tasks. Please use this tag together with one for the associated programming language.
>
> A library is a group of pre-compiled functions which a computer program may call.
>
> Use this tag when seeking recommendations for libraries in conjunction with a language tag, such as c#, c++, java, javascript, php, … or a platform tag such as .net, …

They don't have a language-agnostic tag though ...